# my app creates the /var/mobile/ folder but I can't find it in Finder

Tags: ios, xcode5, clang

My Xcode app creates a document and resource path. Please see the console output below when I print out these two path variables:

[image]

However, when I try to find this folder in Finder, I'm told the folder doesn't exist.

[image]

Why?!

The code for getting the two paths are below:

```
// Get the path to the resource directory.
    NSString* resourcePath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    std::string *resourcePathCPP = new std::string([resourcePath UTF8String]);

    // Get the path to the Documents direcotory
    NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentsPath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    std::string *documentsPathCPP = new std::string([documentsPath UTF8String]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `/var/mobile` folder is on your iOS device, not your computer.

Comment: wow...don't I feel stupid. Thanks rmaddy.

Answer (score 0):

That should be on your iPhone/iPad's file system, not on your Mac. Otherwise **Go to folder ...** Is the right way to check a directory.